# Sending keystrokes through COM port without hardware

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, com

I'm running a piece of Software on Windows 7 (64 bit) that takes keyboard input through a COM port. I never had any of those, so what I used so far is an external PS2 to COM keyboard converter (hardware).
However, this solution is very limiting as I have to use PS2 keyboards. Instead, I want to find some way to send the input directly into the software from the normal keyboard connected to the computer, without the use of external hardware. I tried searching for virtual drivers and other software solutions but I can't seem to find something that does the trick.

Does anyone have any idea? I want to avoid any hardware solutions because I will soon be required to solve this on a large number of computers.

Answer (score 0):

There are various "virtual serial port" drivers which give you either a pair of serial ports (e.g. you write to COM1A and the program reads from COM1B), or a TCP-connected port (you connect to localhost:1234, send data, and the program reads it from COM1).

Most of them are commercial products; com0com is open-source but does not provide signed drivers.